# How do vectors clean up after themselves? (Or do they?)

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, vector

I'm making a game that simulates skeet shooting for my programming class.
The main `Game` class contains `std::vector<Bullet> bullets`, where `Bullet` is my class. It contains only members of concrete types, and overrides a base `Drawable` class to draw and update itself. It does not redefine any operators. At every frame, `bullets` is looped through, and each bullet is updated and drawn.

When the user presses a key, I'm adding a `Bullet` to `bullets` like so:

In Game :: handleInput:

```
if (ui.isSpaceBar())
{
   Bullet newBullet = rifle.fire();
   addBullet(newBullet);
}
```

`rifle.fire` returns a `Bullet` like so:

```
Bullet Rifle :: fire()
{
   ... calculation of position and velocity...
   return Bullet(...position and velocity values...);
}
```

and `addBullet` looks like this:

```
void addBullet(const Bullet & newBullet)
{
   bool assigned = false;
   for (int i = 0; i < bullets.size(); i++)
   {
      // If the i'th bullet is off-screen or hit something ...
      if (bullets[i].isDead())
      {
         // ... then overwrite it with the new bullet,
         // instead of using push_back, to avoid constantly
         // increasing the size of the vector
         bullets[i] = newBullet;
         assigned = true;
         break;
      }
   }

   if (!assigned)
      bullets.push_back(newBullet);
}
```

My question is about the line `bullets[i] = newBullet;`. Do I need to `delete` anything before overwriting the value in the vector using the indexer? If I understand correctly, using values instead of pointers (`Bullet` instead of `Bullet *`, and `return Bullet(...)` instead of `return new Bullet(...)`) means I don't ever have to call `delete`, and the `Bullet` instances are destroyed automatically when they go out of scope, which will be when the vector goes out of scope. Is that right? If so, does using the vector's indexer operator `delete` the old value (the "dead" bullet, in this case)? If not, what am I missing? And should I be using pointers instead of values?

Comment: No, you don't need to call delete. In fact, doing so would probably crash your program. You can't delete what wasn't explicitly new'd. If all the elements of the vector are of the same type, you don't need to use pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use concrete objects (e.g. `Bullet`) instead of pointers to objects you don't need to use delete.

So `bullets[i] = myBullet` makes a copy of `myBullet`.  It assigns the old value of `bullets[i]` with the new value of `myBullet`.  When the vector goes out of scope it will call each of it's elements destructor which cleans up any memory held by the element.

To be technically correct, the above statement uses the assignment operator (`operator=`), to make the copy.  That does whatever is needed to clean up the old `bullet` and copy the new `bullet's` member variables to the old `bullet's` member variables.

`bullets.push_back(myBullet)` is similar.  Except it adds `myBullet` to  the end of the vector.  So that means if the vector had a size of 9 it will now be 10.

To be technically correct, the `push_back` uses a copy constructor, as opposed to the assignment operator, to construct the new object (I think) since there is no existing old `bullet` object.

The bottom line is that given a correctly implemented concrete class (no matter how complicated it is internally) you can use instances of them in `std::vector` and not worry about doing any memory cleanup.

Comment: Thank you. This confirms what I thought I knew. What I'm still not clear on, though, is what happens when `bullets[i]` already has a value when `myBullet` is assigned to it. Is the existing value (the "dead" bullet) destroyed, and all allocations for it cleaned automatically?

Comment: Yes.  But I've added a fuller explanation in the answer.  You can better understand how these operations work by looking at the above mentioned member functions of Bullet.

Comment: @MichaelHoffmann the *assignment operator* is used. There's no construction and destruction (unless the assignment operator function explicitly implements itself by destructing the old and constructing a new).  If you did not declare your own `Bullet::operator=` function, the compiler makes one for you which behaves as if you went `x = other.x;` etc. where `x` is each member variable of the class in turn.

Comment: Ah, I see. So the default implementation does nothing as far as disposing of `other`? How does the default assignment operator behave with pointers? (Better yet, where can I read more about this?)

Comment: @MichaelHoffmann: You'll want to search for the `Rule of Three` - three member functions that almost always go together: the copy constructor, assignment operator, and destructor. Or the `Rule of Zero` - classes are easier if they don't need any of those three.